# How to Align Text in Android TextView

Tags: android, alignment, textview

I have a TextView in my application. I want to align 2 separate text one ontop of the other. 
But have no idea how. Any suggestions ?

Text code that is to be displayed:

```
String[] product_showcase_list = new String[] {

"Product Name 产品名称 ： Office Chair 1 " +
"Product Serial 产品号码 ：0C012345", 
 ...
}
```

code that is used to call out String text:

```
label_col_1_datatab3.setText(product_showcase_list[cnt]);
```

Currently, what is being displayed on the screen:

```
Product Name 产品名称 ： Office Chair 1 Product Serial 产品号码 ：0C012345
```

How it is needed to be displayed:

```
Product Name 产品名称 ： Office Chair 1 
Product Serial 产品号码 ：0C012345
```

Comment: You can use two textView separately.

Comment: two different textview one for showing name other for product serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try adding "\n" after your number one. In your String

"Product Name 产品名称 ： Office Chair 1 \n" +
"Product Serial 产品号码 ：0C012345"

- Or Use two TextViews in a LinearLayout or ListView

Answer (score 1):

Within your loop, change as below.

```
String temp = product_showcase_list[cnt] + "\n"
label_col_1_datatab3.setText(temp);
```

Hope it helps!